# How to set two jquery functions with one identify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I need use two jQuery functions with one ID working on edge and chrome browsers. Chrome works perfect but edge don't.

```js
$("#myInput").keyup(function() {
  $("#myInput").val($(this).val().replace(",", "."));
});

$("#myInput").change(function() {
  alert("hello world");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

Can you explain me why and how to solve it.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: Other than the keyup performing an unnecessary lookup in the event handler, I do not see any syntax issues.

Comment: changing value as the user types might create bugs. Also no reason to change it when there is nothing to change.

Comment: Ok, bit odd...  looks like the `.val()` is resetting the value that kicks in for `.change` in IE.  So because you call `.val("val")` when it's ready the trigger the change event, it checks if it's changed - but hasn't changed - so doesn't fire the change event.  Suggest you either use `.blur` or store/update the initial value in a `data-value` `$(#myInput").data("orig", $(#myInput").val())`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this:

Change entering a comma to entering a fullstop and trigger the hello after 1 second of inactivity

```js
var tId;
$("#myInput").on("keypress", function(e) {
  clearTimeout(tId);
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == ",") {
    this.value += ".";
    e.preventDefault();
  }  
  tId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hello")
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

Comment: Thats not what i mean. Purpose of my question is automatic change comma to dot in input and work with that value in edge and chrome.

Comment: So entering a dot when you press comma is not useful? Strange - anyway what about the alert you have. When should it show?

Comment: It should show after end writing text. Your code show alert after every writen character.

Comment: No, only when you pause for more than a second. Change 1000 to 3000

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the Edge browser, the change event will not trigger, you could try to trigger the change function in the jquery focusout event, code as below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#myInput").keyup(function () {
            $("#myInput").val($(this).val().replace(",", "."));
            console.log("keyup event trigger");

        });
        $("#myInput").focusout(function () {

            //check whether it is Edge browser
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
            if (edge > 0) {
                $("#myInput").trigger("change");
            }
        });
        $("#myInput").change(function () {
            //alert("hello world");
            console.log("change event triger");
        });
    })
</script>
```

the result as below:

[image]